# Is using a wrapper with a 'check' function a good approach to optional types rather than the traditional method?

Tags: c++, option-type

languages like C++ and Rust have an Option type, which is basically an enum/bool with a value.

But I feel like this can have a few problems like:

- the extra overhead of returning/passing an extra field with your type
- breaking ABI compatibility if you decide that a function should return an optional instead of the raw value.

So why not instead of putting a bool with the value, have a function associated with the type to check if the value returned is valid or not.

for example:

```
template<typename T, bool(*ISOK)(T&)>
struct Errorable
{
    private:
    T val;

    public:
    Errorable(T v)
    {
        val = v;
    }
    
    bool is_ok()
    {
        return ISOK(val);
    }

    bool is_err()
    {
        return !ISOK(val);
    }

    T unwrap_or(T o)
    {
        if(ISOK(val))
            return val;
        return o;
    };

    T unwrap_forced()
    {
        return val;
    }
};
```

which can be used like:

```
bool idx_ok(int& idx)
{
    return idx >= 0;
}

Errorable<int, idx_ok> array_idx_of(int *arr, int len, int elm)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == elm)
        {
            Errorable<int, idx_ok> ok(i);
            return ok;
        }
    }
    Errorable<int, idx_ok> err(-1);
    return err;
}
```

and then

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto idx = array_index_of(arr, 5, 6);
    if(idx.is_ok())
    { ... }
}
```

<sub>sorry if my C++ is bad, I'm a C programmer who needed templates for a sec</sub>

Comment: calling a function through a function pointer seems to be more work then just checking an internal bool.  the local bool is going to be more cache friendly.  As always though, the only way to really know is to try it and then benchmark it against the alternative.  some use cases may be better than others

Comment: @NathanOliver will it be treated as a function pointer though? since we're passing it as a template the compiler will probably inline it

Comment: Not all types have a suitable "not ok" value that can be leveraged to indicate that things have gone all pear-shaped.

Comment: sorry, but this looks like glorified sentinal values, which is rather limited. A `std::optional<int>` (which is `int`+`bool` against which you compare) allows the whole range of `int` to be valid values and in addtion it has an "empty" state.

Comment: Also, somewhat related: there is [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) in C++23, or [Boost Outcome](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/index.html) for earlier C++ (which strongly influenced `std::expected`).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yeah pretty much. The issue with sentinel values is that they're not enforced to be checked, this kinda solves that. As for the other issue of values that don't have an "invalid" state, Optional makes more sense. But imo the cases where every value is valid are rare.

Comment: I'm closing this as opinion-based. Personally I think this approach is fine in specific cases, but other people are likely of the opinion that you should just use `std::optional` since the overhead is small, or that a custom type is better than one with a function pointer template parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver the function pointer is a template parameter, so it's obviously a constant expression and will get optimized to a static call in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you gave requires that the returned object has some sort of invalid state, but not all objects have such a state.

As an example, the C function `atoi` converts a C-style string to an `int`, and returns `0` if it fails.  The problem is that `0` is also a valid integer.  Since there's no value of of an `int` that can't be the result of successful conversion there's no way to tell just from looking at the return value if `atoi` failed or not.

Your `Errorable` has the same problem.  For instance, if you were to try to write your own `atoi` using `Errorable` you couldn't do any better than the existing implementation.

The value of `std::optional` (and Option types in general) is that they avoid this problem by decoupling the existence of the object from the value of the object.  You could write a `std::optional<int> my_atoi(const char*)` that can return any value in the entire range of an `int` *and* allows you to determine if the function failed to process its input or not.

Comment: yeah, this makes sense. But for cases where there indeed is an error state (most cases?) would you say my approach is better?

Comment: There are probably situations where it's better in some ways.  My point is that your `Errorable` serves a very different purpose than `std::optional`.  It doesn't represent "either no value or a value", but rather "a value that is constrained to some bounds not represented by the type system".

Answer (score 1):

If your function can either return a value, or "no value", then feel free to use `std::optional`:

```
std::optional<int> tryToGetValue() {
  if (condition) return 100;
  else return std::nullopt;
}
```

If your function always returns some value/structure, however that structure invariants are not always satisfied, return a structure with validation function (you can generalize it to provide custom validators, use polymorphism etc.):

```
struct JsonResponse {
  bool isValid();
  int getValue(/* some args */);
  // some logic
};
JsonResponse requestReply(/* ... */);
```

If your function should always return a value, and it doesn't make sense to continue with the rest of your program logic if that value is invalid, then throw the exception:

```
int getElement(int idx) {
  if (container.size() <= idx) throw std::logic_error("idx out of bounds");
}
```

Try to always prioritize the semantics, and write the code that expresses the intent. Then later (only for experts!) you can try to profile it and optimize.